# Use of fmin in python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use fmin to minize my function:

```
def minim(self,x_r,x_i):
    self.a=complex(3,4)*(3*np.exp(1j*self.L_ch))
    x = x_r + x_i
    self.T=np.array([[0.0,2.0*self.a],[(0.00645+(x_r)^2), 4.3*x_i^2]])
    return self.T

part_real=0.532
part_imag=1.2
R_0 = fmin(A.minim,part_real,part_imag)
```

but i got this error:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 268, in function_wrapper
    return function(x, *args)
TypeError: minim() argument after * must be a sequence, not float
```

I tried to use something else like minimize but the same error appear. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that accurately replicates your problem?

Comment: From this it doesn't seem like you are using fmin correctly. Is your initial guess x0 = x_r + x_i*1j? If so, then you need to input it as that format, you can't give your x0 in the way you have. If they are meant to be arguments, then you need to pass them to the function as a tuple, e.g. args = (part_real,part_imag). You should read the manual for fmin first to be sure you're using it correctly: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `fmin` correctly.

`scipy.optimize.fmin(func, x0, args=(), xtol=0.0001, ftol=0.0001, maxiter=None, maxfun=None, full_output=0, disp=1, retall=0, callback=None)`. If you want to optimize for both `x_r` and `x_i`, you should pass them together as `x0`. The way you are doing it now passes `part_imag` as `args`, which should be a sequence, not a scalar. That's why your get an exception

Without an reproducible example, I guess you need to change your code to:

```
def minim(self,p):
    x_r=p[0]
    x_i=p[1]
    self.a=complex(3,4)*(3*np.exp(1j*self.L_ch))
    x = x_r + x_i
    self.T=np.array([[0.0,2.0*self.a],[(0.00645+(x_r)^2), 4.3*x_i^2]])
    return self.T

part_real=0.532
part_imag=1.2
R_0 = fmin(A.minim,[part_real,part_imag])
```

And see if it works.

Also your `x` seems never get used.