# fmin python error numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use fmin to minize my function, you find example below of my function, with a class :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import sys,os
import numpy as np
from math import exp
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fmin

from carlo import *

A=real()

x_r=0.11245
x_i=0.14587

C=A.minim([x_r,x_i])
part_real=0.532
part_imag=1.2
R_0 = fmin(C,[part_real,part_imag])
```

This is my class : (name carlo.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import sys,os
import numpy as np
import random, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath
#pdb.set_trace()

class real:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nmodes = 4
        self.L_ch = 1
        self.w = 2

    def minim(self,p):

        x_r=p[0]
        x_i=p[1]
        self.a=complex(3,4)*(3*np.exp(1j*self.L_ch))
        self.T=np.array([[0.0,2.0*self.a],[(0.00645+(x_r)**2), 4.3*x_i**2]])
        self.Id=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
        self.disp=np.linalg.det(self.T-self.Id)
        return self.disp
```

I have this error :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 281, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
TypeError: 'numpy.complex128' object is not callable
```

I tried to work it but i don't understand this error if i return just T i have error : TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable. Please help me, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740046/use-of-fmin-in-python/21740547?noredirect=1#comment32917062_21740547

Comment: Change `C=A.minim([x_r,x_i])` to just `C=A.minim`, the first argument for `fmin` has to be callable: a function or a method.